# Convert rtf to sag to be used as IMG in html

Tags: svg

I have been provided with some rtf files that are to be used for inline svgs. I want to reference the sag externally but when I use any `rtf` to `svg` converters it converts it into an sag image with the code.

See screenshot showing the svg after I have tried convert it from an `rtf` file.

[image]

Does anyone know how to convert an rtf file to an svgs that i can reference as an `img src` in my html?

Comment: @RobertLongson that isn't the code. That is the svg once it is converted from a `rtf` file.

Comment: It's a screenshot, it should be text. What's your problem using it as-is as an img src?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the text from the rtf file and put it into code editor/notepad, and save with the `.svg` extension. If this is too much hassle (because you have many files) look for a tool that converts `rtf` to `txt`, and then change the extension to `svg`.